# Monitoring second battery in Android

Tags: android, embedded, battery

Need a help from Android systems guru.

We have an embedded project that consists of Android smartphone and custom embedded device connected via USB. Embedded device has its own battery and I need to monitor its status.

Is it possible to register second battery in Android system? We could provide callbacks or driver or whatever for Android to query battery status over USB.

As I saw in [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) and [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) API there is only notion of a single battery and there are no methods for "adding" or "registering" new battery.

Maybe there is something in NDK? Maybe we should make second battery appear in /sys, so Android will automatically detect it? Will it even work?

Or we have to stick with writing ordinary application that will query status over USB and display it in activity?